# CombineLatest hiding error

Tags: android, rx-java2

I want to retrieve a list of places with a distance, and append this distance only if there is a last location available.

My Last location provider is an `Observable` that emits `onNext` if it has a location or completes if not.

So I've tried with this:

```
val combineLatest = Flowable
                .combineLatest<List<Place>, Location, List<Place>>(
                        req,
                        getLastLocation().lastOrError().toFlowable()
                        ,
                        BiFunction { places, loc ->
                            places.forEach {

                                var placeLocation = Location(it.placeName)
                                placeLocation.latitude = it.latitude
                                placeLocation.longitude = it.longitude

                                it.distance = location?.distanceTo(placeLocation)
                            }
                            places.sortedBy {
                                it.distance
                            }
                        })
        combineLatest.onErrorResumeNext { t: Throwable ->

            req
        }
```

What I'm trying to do is attempt to calculate the distance based on the last known location, or return the original request untouched if not.

However when location is not there, getLastLocation completes without emitting, and thus `lastOrError` fails with `NoSuchElementException`. However, this error is not intercepted by my onErrorResumeNext statement, so I cannot put my fallback in.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Is this a method call? Looks like you ignore the flow `combineLatest.onErrorResumeNext` returns.

Comment: omg you are right this is the method body and I just return combineLatest instead of that